# User Defined Function with Passing Object

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I just wanted help in creating my own function which passes with the object as reference.

```
Set Pg = Browser("Browser").Page("Login")
Pg.WebEdit("loginForm:userName").cSet("user1")

Public Function cSet(obj, val)
    If IsOBject(Obj) Then  ''Here obj is WebEdit("loginForm:userName")
        Obj.Set val  '''Here val is user1
    Else
        Reporter.ReportEvent micFail,"Failed","Object not found"
    End If
End Function
```

Getting the below error

> Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Browser(...).Page(...).WebEdit(...).cSet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve here. `WebEdit` already has a `Set` function that will fail if the object does not exist.

In any case UFT allows adding (or overriding) functions for specific test objects, see the documentation for [`RegisterUserFunc`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.03/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/TEST_work_w_UDF.htm).

For example, if an object doesn't exist UFT will wait for it to exist until a timeout passes. You can tell UFT to fail immediately if the object does not exist.

```
' Define the function
Function QuickSet(ByRef obj, ByVal value) 
    If Not obj.Exist(0) Then ' zero means don't wait 
        Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "QuickSet", "Object does not exist"
        Exit Function
    End If
    obj.Set value   
End Function

' Register the function to WebEdit as a new function
RegisterUserFunc "WebEdit", "QuickSet", "QuickSet"

' Or override the default behaviour of Set
RegisterUserFunc "WebEdit", "Set", "QuickSet"
```